# QGIS modelbuilder, having a choicebox/value map of strings as string input

Tags: qgis-modeler

I was wondering how you can get a choicebox/value map in the string input? Right now we have to type in value in but we would like to have it that has a choicebox/listbox to save time with typing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have kind of found my answer though it is kind of annoying **and I wish there was a better one.**

**STEP ONE:**

To get a choice box you have to use the FIELD MAPPER input parameter and then define your choices there. **However keep in mind that these are actually numbers that need to be converted to strings.**

**STEP TWO:**

The problem is however when you convert a number to a string, you of course do not have the actual value of the mapper. To make sure it gets the right value you build a CASE EXPRESION in the column where the value is to be inputed.

```
CASE 
WHEN to_string(@achtergrondondergrond2) ='0'
THEN
'GRB'
WHEN to_string(@achtergrondondergrond2) ='1'
THEN
'CADMAP'
WHEN to_string(@achtergrondondergrond2) ='2'
THEN
'KADVEC'
WHEN to_string(@achtergrondondergrond2) ='3'
THEN
'KADSCAN'
WHEN to_string(@achtergrondondergrond2) ='4'
THEN
'WPB'
WHEN to_string(@achtergrondondergrond2) ='5'
THEN
'TOPO'
WHEN to_string(@achtergrondondergrond2) ='6'
THEN
'ANDERE'
ELSE
null 
End
```

**And your done, wish there was a better solution but this is the best we can do now apparently.**